# Is it appropriate to ask for a review of an Entity Relationship Diagram on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want a second opinion on my Entity Relationship Diagram, the tables I've created from it, and normalization. Is this question appropriate for Stack Overflow

I think it isn't, but I'd like to ask the question. Where would be the best place to ask this?

Comment: I would say no for SO, but perhaps for the Programmers Stack Exchange. I am however not an active participant over there, so first make sure to have a look at that site and verify if it might be on-topic. (Or perhaps one of their users can weigh in on that here).

Comment: Considering your question is about data-modelling it might as well fit on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

No, that doesn't seem like a good fit for Stack Overflow and asking for opinions / reviews is tricky on most SE sites.

For the design aspects of Software Engineering you can check  [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are for

> professionals, academics, and students working within the systems development life cycle.
>
> If you have a question about...
>
> - requirements, architecture, and design

They do have a [normalization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/normalization/info) tag but it doesn't look like they offer much on ERD's specific. They do have guidance on how to ask [Design review questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6504/99854) (kindly provided by @gnat) so a carefully crafted question might work there.

However I believe [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) is a better choice as they are for

> those needing expert answers to advanced database-related questions concerning traditional SQL RDBMS and NoSQL alternatives.

They do have an [ERD](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erd) tag which you could use as a starting point to see if the type of question you want to ask is well received there.

When in doubt ask on either sites meta, presenting them with your actual question to prevent any misrepresentation of their topic-ness or scope by me.

Comment: SE.SE has a specific meta guidance for that matter: [Are Design Review questions on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6504/31260)